# При любом использовании команды "pip install " возникает ошибка: "ERROR: Could not install package due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

OS: Windows 7 32 bit
Python 3.7.3

Ошибка:

> ERROR: Could not install package due to an EnvironmentError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool

Comment: Используете прокси? Попробуйте `pip --proxy "здесь_ваш_прокси" install `. Ну или в trusted-host добавить хост.

Answer (score 1):

Используете прокси? Попробуйте добавить адреса в доверенные:

```
sudo pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade --proxy=ваш_прокси
```

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5309

Comment: Нет, прокси не используется. Возможно проблема в том что я раздаю интернет с телефона?

Comment: @molchaliviy с питоном не так много работал =/ Я в ответ приложил ссылку на оригинал совета, может поможет.

Comment: в любом случае спасибо, буду ждать ещё ответов (надеюсь они будут))